# Keras single Image prediction not working with correct dims

Tags: keras

I want to predict single images with the functional API (keras version 2.2.2, tensorflow backend v1.7) . I load my model:

```
# Loading Model
base_model = VGG16(include_top = False,  weights=None,
              input_shape=(224,224,3))
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dropout(0.7)(x)
x = Dense(1020, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

model.load_weights("model.h5")
```

Then I load an Image and transform it into the input format and try to predict:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
img = load_img("data/my_image.png")  # this is a PIL image
array = img_to_array(img)  # this is a Numpy array with shape 
arrayresized = cv2.resize(array, (244,244))*1./255 
inputarray = np.expand_dims(arrayresized, axis=0)

# Predicting
prediction = model.predict(inputarray, batch_size = 1)
```

Then I get this error back:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_4 to have shape 
(224, 224, 3) but got array with shape (244, 244, 3)
```

Comment: Shapes are incompatible. Either pass `input_shape=(244,244,3)` to `VGG16` or pass `(224,224)` to `cv2.resize()`.

Comment: I resize into (244,244) with cv2. According to the error the expected input shape is the shape of the array it got. Weird

Comment: Pay attention: one is **244**, the other is **224**.